# Create a pull request in Azure DevOps using JavaScript via a GUI?

Tags: javascript, azure-devops, frontend, cdn, productize

I've been looking for a market standard approach to productize a frontend web application.

We could figure out a way to use CDN in this case, where the assets (texts, images etc) would be fetched from the CDN on the fly. But to deploy a new version of CDN that needs to be done using a pull request in Azure DevOps.

Does anyone know if we can run Azure command using JavaScript via the GUI where it can create a pull request?

**For eg:** If a user upload an image and add some text and click "Submit" I want to create a pull request to the repository (which would deploy a new CDN version with those changes) using JavaScript with some Azure/Github API's (if that's possible).

I would also like to know from some of you if this a best solution to achieve productization for a frontend web app or using a regular backend API and database tables?

Apologies for being subjective. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

To create a pull request, you can use REST API [Pull Requests - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-requests/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP). The following is a sample of calling this REST API using JavaScript for your reference.

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa('Basic' + ":" + '{Your PAT}'));

var raw = JSON.stringify({
    "sourceRefName": "refs/heads/"{Your source branch}",
    "targetRefName": "refs/heads/{Your target branch}",
    "title": "{PR title}",
    "description": "{The description of your PR}",
    "reviewers": [
        {
            "id": "{User id of the reviewer. If you don't need a reviewer, you can ignore}"
        }
    ]
});

var requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: myHeaders,
    body: raw
};

fetch("https://dev.azure.com/{Org name}/{project name}/_apis/git/repositories/{Repo name or ID}/pullrequests?api-version=7.1-preview.1", requestOptions)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(result => console.log(result))
    .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Replace the content inside { } according to your needs.